Invoke dependent lambda functions, avoiding cold start
I have a system that comprises nextjs, talking to fastapi, talking to edgedb, talking to aurora. In order to save on costs, I would like to run the three services on lambda functions. I am aware of the limitations regarding cold starts.
In my use-case, if the fastapi lambda is invoked, it will definitely talk to the database, meaning that the edgedb lambda will also be invoked, and in most cases, if the nextjs lambda is invoked, it will hit fastapi lambda.
Is there a mechanism for telling API Gateway that if the nextjs lambda is invoked, it should wake up the other two as well, in order to avoid three sequential cold starts?

That's a very specific thing you're asking for ("Is there a mechanism for telling API Gateway that if the nextjs lambda is invoked, it should wake up the other two as well") and the answer is "almost certainly not". You might consider using provisioned concurrency, however.

I would have thought that in a serverless application, the idea that there might be some correlation between when lambdas get invoked would be pretty common, but I'm far from being sure. Thank you for the suggestion of provisioned concurrency.

It's not inconceivable that AWS could attempt to optimize this within Step Functions because it knows what the invocation hierarchy is most likely going to be, but I doubt it for arbitrary Lambda functions.

To avoid cold start in lambda functions you can use Lambda SnapStart, it will capture the snapshot and caches of the  initialization happen in lambda function and reuses instead of doing initialization each time.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart.html
Follow the steps provided here to activate,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart-activate.html
But right now the Lambda SnapStart supports very few environments ,
Java 11 and later Java managed runtimes.

But, as you say, it's Java only so doesn't seem to be appropriate here.

Apologies, got little misunderstanding with the documentation. Just now tried it lambda console.

That won't work for me here, but it's an interesting feature that I didn't know about. Thank you.
